How could I further improve my detection model?
I am currently tasked with the creation of a model which is able to detect burrows of small rodents from high resolution aerial images.
My labeled images are look like this:

My results now are the following.


I can see that my false positives are a bit too much. This would be my primary focus to reduce.
Here are some details about what I do right now.

I automatically label my images. All are in brownish in colour and I know a point which is on the burrow. I use this information to highlight similar pixels and collect them into a bounding box.
For this part I got a suggestion that I should only train on these points and extend my model to be compatible with this form
I use YOLOv9c as my model. I use the pretrained version for it. The one without training yielded in worse results. I didn't modfied or added any layer to this model
I don't do any preprocess on the images. I dabbled with gaussian blur and clahe
I have 300 images sized 640x640 to use for training

Here are some things I tried to do:

Add background images without any objects. I tried with about 5% of the images as background.
Yolov9c model without pretrained weights
some preprocess on the images
tuning the model (I only ran it for 30 epoch and 300 iterations)


You might want to consider using higher resolution images if possible. Even for a human, distinguishing rodent burrows from patches of missing grass can be challenging, so increasing the image resolution could help both you and the model differentiate these small objects more accurately.
If false positives are your main concern, adjusting the confidence threshold could help. Raising the threshold should reduce false positives, but keep in mind it may also lead to more missed detections.
It's important to closely review the model's errors. Determine whether it's truly detecting burrows or getting confused by dark patches or missing grass. Understanding these patterns will allow you to address the specific issues, possibly by increasing augmentation on images where burrows appear in grassy areas.
You didn't mention using data augmentation, but make sure you're applying basic techniques like rotation and brightness/contrast adjustments. These are crucial for helping the model generalize better.Also, double-check that your ground truth data is accurate and complete. Missing burrows in your labels could negatively impact the model's performance.
Consider looking into similar research to see what models and techniques others are using. Adding more relevant data could also help—try finding additional rodent burrow datasets online. It might be worth exploring pre-trained models that are trained on aerial data, such as those available on Roboflow.
Finally, 30 epochs might be on the lower side, but this varies depending on the dataset. Check your training and validation curves to ensure you're not overfitting.
